# Author handling node view access?

Tags: views, users

First post here! ;) I'm not getting any help from the Drupal forums on this, maybe someone can help me out...Does anyone know of a module that I can use so that an Author can allow access to a user requesting access to the Author's node.
The setup would be like this:
1. An Author would create a private node, but viewable in teaser form.
2. Any Authenticated user could then request access to the node/full view.
3. The Author would then have a queue, say in their own user environment, where he/she could approve or deny access to the node/full view for the requesting user.
Thank you very much!

Comment: how scalable does this have to be? Are you thinking of tens, hundreds or thousands of users getting access to a node? Is "hiding a link" good enough or do you need robust access control? Access will be granted for a specific node, not  for all nodes of the author, right? Finally, Dupal 6 or 7?

Comment: Hey Mototribe! Thanks for the reply! Most nodes would only need about maybe 10 users tops. I'm not sure if hiding a link makes sense, maybe I'm not understanding the idea? Yes only specific nodes that a user wants access to. Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about building a simple access system, but that would be like re-inventing the wheel.

Take a look at [content_access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) in combination with [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl). The [flexiaccess](http://drupal.org/project/flexiaccess) might be another option.

Comment: I looked at all of this individually today. Maybe I need to combine them all in some way. Thanks!